# Finding the eigenvalues and eigenfunctions to this sturm-liouville operator

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, operator-theory, sturm-liouville

I am asked to find the eigenvalues and eigenfunctions to the operator $A$, defined by
$$Au = -\frac{d^2u}{dx^2}-6\frac{du}{dx}$$
and also $0<x<L, \quad u(0) = u(L) = 0$.

Rewriting the operator to sturm-liouville form gives
$$Au = -\frac{1}{e^{6x}}(e^{6x}u')'.$$

To find the eigenvalues, eigenvectors I am solving
$$Au = \lambda u \iff -u''-6u'-\lambda u = 0$$
where the characteristic equation $x^2 + 6x + \lambda = 0$ has solution $x=-3\pm \sqrt{9-\lambda}.$

What can I say about $\lambda$ to further solve this? How do I proceed? And how do I incorporate the restrictions on $u$?

The solution is supposed to be
$$\lambda_k = 9 + (\frac{k\pi}{L})^2$$
$$u_k(x) = e^{-3x}\sin{\frac{k\pi}{L}x}, \ k=1,2,.....$$

Answer (score 1):

The key is to notice that $\lambda>9$ and the characteristic equation has two complex roots that are conjugates of one another.

The general solution is $u(x)=Ce^{q_1 x} + De^{q_2 x}$ where

$q_1=-3+i\sqrt{\lambda-9}$ and $q_2=-3-i\sqrt{\lambda-9}$ are the complex roots of the characteristic equation

This is equivalent to $u=e^{-3x}(Acos(\sqrt{\lambda-9}x)+Bsin(\sqrt{\lambda-9} x))$

The boundary conditions require $B=0$ and $\sqrt{\lambda-9}L=k\pi$, which gives the desired form for u. Substituting this in the original differential equation gives

$\lambda=9+(\frac{k\pi}{L})^2$

Comment: Thank you. But how do I notice that $\lambda > 9$?

Comment: Well we are given the solution $\lambda=9+(\frac{k\pi}{L})^2$ and the task is to verify that solution, is that right? Anyway, if $\lambda \le 9$ then you get $u=Ee^{ax} + Fe^{bx}$ with a,b real and thus $u\ne 0$, so the boundary conditions cannot be satisfied.

Comment: no the solution is not given in the problem. But okay I think I see now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

$$
             Af=\lambda f \iff -f''-6f'=\lambda f
$$
To normalize the solutions, set $f(0)=0$ and $f'(0)=1$. Assume that $f=e^{\alpha x}$. Then
$$
                 -\alpha^2-6\alpha=\lambda \\
                   \alpha^2+6\alpha=-\lambda \\
                  (\alpha+3)^2=9-\lambda\\
                 \alpha = -3 \pm \sqrt{9-\lambda}
$$
The solutions so far are
$$
        f(x)=e^{-3x}\frac{\sin(\sqrt{\lambda-9}x)}{\sqrt{\lambda-9}}
$$
Now the condition $f(L)=0$ determines the eigenvalues $\lambda$:
$$
              \frac{ \sin(\sqrt{\lambda-9}L)}{\sqrt{\lambda-9}}=0.
$$
$\lambda=9$ is not a solution because the limit of the above as $\lambda\rightarrow 9$ is non-zero. The solutions are
$$
            \lambda = 9+n^2\pi^2/L^2,\;\;\; n=1,2,3,\cdots.
$$
The resulting eigenfunctions are
$$
              f_n = e^{-3x}\frac{\sin(n\pi x/L)}{n\pi/L},\;\;\; n=1,2,3,\cdots.
$$